# Parsing numbers from strings in lisp

Tags: parsing, text, lisp, common-lisp

Here's the brief problem:
Input: a list of strings, each containing numbers
("  3.4 5.4 1.2 6.4" "7.8 5.6 4.3" "1.2 3.2 5.4")

Output: a list of numbers
(3.4 5.4 1.2 6.4 7.8 5.6 4.3 1.2 3.2 5.4)

Here's my attempt at coding this:

```
(defun parse-string-to-float (line &optional (start 0))
  "Parses a list of floats out of a given string"
  (if (equalp "" line)
    nil
    (let ((num (multiple-value-list (read-from-string (subseq line start)))))
      (if (null (first num))
        nil
        (cons (first num) (parse-string-to-float (subseq line (+ start (second num)))))))))

(defvar *data* (list "  3.4 5.4 1.2 6.4" "7.8 5.6 4.3" "1.2 3.2 5.4"))

(setf *data* (format nil "~{~a ~}" *data*))

(print (parse-string-to-float *data*))

===> (3.4 5.4 1.2 6.4 7.8 5.6 4.3 1.2 3.2 5.4)
```

However, for rather large data sets, it's a slow process. I'm guessing the recursion isn't as tight as possible and I'm doing something unnecessary. Any ideas?

Furthermore, the grand project involves taking an input file that has various data sections separated by keywords. Example -

```
%FLAG START_COORDS
1   2   5   8   10   12  
%FLAG END_COORDS  
3   7   3   23   9   26
%FLAG NAMES
ct  re  ct  cg  kl   ct
```

etc...
I'm trying to parse a hash-table with the keywords that follow %FLAG as the keys, and the values stored as number or string lists depending on the particular keyword I'm parsing. Any ideas for libraries that already do this very type of job, or simple ways around this in lisp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a task you want to be doing recursively to begin with. Instead, use `LOOP` and a `COLLECT` clause. For example:

```
(defun parse-string-to-floats (line)
  (loop
    :with n := (length line)
    :for pos := 0 :then chars
    :while (< pos n)
    :for (float chars) := (multiple-value-list
            (read-from-string line nil nil :start pos))
    :collect float))
```

Also, you might want to consider using `WITH-INPUT-FROM-STRING` instead of `READ-FROM-STRING`, which makes things even simpler.

```
(defun parse-string-to-float (line)
  (with-input-from-string (s line)
    (loop
      :for num := (read s nil nil)
      :while num
      :collect num)))
```

As for performance, you might want to do some profiling, and ensure that you are actually compiling your function.

**EDIT** to add: One thing you do need to be careful of is that the reader can introduce a security hole if you're not sure of the source of the string. There's a read macro, `#.`, which can allow evaluation of arbitrary code following it when it's read from a string. The best way to protect yourself is by binding the [`*READ-EVAL*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/v_rd_eva.htm) variable to `NIL`, which will make the reader signal an error if it encounters `#.`. Alternatively, you can use one of the specialized libraries that [Rainer Joswig mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1496779/85467).

Comment: with-input-from-string?  Wow!  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 10):

**Parse a single string**:

```
(defun parse-string-to-floats (string)
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
    (with-input-from-string (stream string)
      (loop for number = (read stream nil nil)
            while number collect number))))
```

**Process a list of strings and return a single list**:

```
(defun parse-list-of-strings (list)
  (mapcan #'parse-string-to-floats list))
```

**Example**:

```
CL-USER 114 > (parse-list-of-strings (list "1.1 2.3 4.5" "1.17 2.6 7.3"))
(1.1 2.3 4.5 1.17 2.6 7.3)
```

**Note**:

A costly operation is READ to read float values from streams. There are libraries like [PARSE-NUMBER](http://www.cliki.net/PARSE-NUMBER) that might be more efficient - some Common Lisp implementation also might have the equivalent of a READ-FLOAT / PARSE-FLOAT function.

Answer (score 2):

Also for performance, try

```
(declare (optimize (speed 3)))
```

inside your defun. Some lisps (for example SBCL) will print helpful messages about where it could not optimize, and the estimated cost of not having this optimization

Answer (score 2):

As for performance, try at least measuring the memory allocation. I guess that all the performance is eaten by memory allocation and GC: you allocate a lot of big strings with subseq. E.g., (time (parse-string-to-float ..)) will show you how much time is spent in your code, how much in GC and how much memory was allocated.

If this is the case, then use string-stream (like in with-input-from-string) to decrease GC pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

`(SETQ NUMBERS " 3.4 5.4 1.2 6.4")
(READ-FROM-STRING (CONCATENATE 'STRING "(" NUMBERS ")"))`

The idea is to turn the list of numbers into a string that looks like a Lisp list of numbers and then let READ-FROM-STRING do the work of parsing it.  This worked when I tried it in Clisp.